# Implementing Mongodb query using $elemMatch in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I am using Mongo java driver to retrieve data from mongo collections. I have the following query which I am trying to implement in java:
Json is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cd284767c74d3d4dd3ec80"),
    "comments" : "Hello",
    "statusLog" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "Submitted",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2015-01-14T05:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2016-02-29T21:24:24.740Z")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "Active",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2016-02-29T21:24:24.740Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-01-14T05:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Mongo Query:

```
db.CollectionName.find({},{_id: 0, createdDate:1, "statusLog": {$elemMatch: {"status":"Submitted"}}});
```

Here is the query in java that I have written (mongo java driver 3.4.2):

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("statusLog",
                new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("status", "Submitted"))));
```

Running the java code returns all status logs and not the one that I am looking for.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please review the answer again - I've added a comment now. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elemMatch` should be in find method not in projection bson. For example:

```
collection.find(elemMatch("statusLog", eq("status", "Submitted"))).projection(projection);
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it only check if there exists a status log with status as submitted and it returns the **entire** document. Use elemmatch in projection to limit the status log to return the matching element only.  More here [`$elemMatch in projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#mongodb-projection-proj.-elemMatch) - Compare with [`$elemMatch in query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#-elemmatch--query)

Answer (score 4):

You should use newer `Document/MongoCollection` api and use helper methods to prepare projection.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(); 
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db"); // Get DB

MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection"); // Get Collection
Bson projection = Projections.fields( excludeId(), include("createdDate"), elemMatch("statusLog", eq("status", "Submitted"))); // Add Projections
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find().projection(projection);
```

Using old `BasicDBObject/DBCollection` api

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("db");

DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("statusLog",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("status", "Submitted"))));
collection.find(new BasicDBObject(), projection);
```

Answer (score 0):

- To find an item in a list of document with multiple objects, using multiple filtrer criteria:

  "array_of_data": {$elemMatch: {"AAA": "xxxx", "BBB": "xxxxx"}}